# Using i18n select pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to use [**`I18nSelectPipe`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/I18nSelectPipe-pipe.html7). I have the following `code`:

```
this.criteria = [];
this.criteria.push({
  id: 1,
  name: 'ab'
});
this.criteria.push({
  id: 2,
  name: 'cd'
});
this.criteria.push({
  id: 3,
  name: 'ef'
});

this.criteriaChoice = {};
this.criteriaChoice['1'] = 'One';
this.criteriaChoice['2'] = 'Two';
this.criteriaChoice['3'] = 'Three';
```

In `HTML`:

```
<div *ngFor="let criterium of criteria">
  <strong>{{criterium.id | i18nSelect: criteriaChoice}}</strong>
</div>
```

As you may have noticed, I'm trying simply translate a "key" using that *pipe*, but it always returns me the following error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '[object Object]' for pipe
>   'I18nSelectPipe'

If I try something simple as below, it works:

```
<strong>{{'1' | i18nSelect: criteriaChoice}}</strong>
```

How can I solve this?

By the way, it's a sample code, the code isn't hardcoded this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`<strong>{{criterium.id+'' | i18nSelect: criteriaChoice}}</strong>`

I had the same problem with a boolean value using Angular 2.4.10.

When I looked at the code:

```
I18nSelectPipe.prototype.transform = function (value, mapping) {
    if (value == null)
        return '';
    if (typeof mapping !== 'object' || typeof value !== 'string') {
        throw new InvalidPipeArgumentError(I18nSelectPipe, mapping);
    }
    if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        return mapping[value];
    }
    if (mapping.hasOwnProperty('other')) {
        return mapping['other'];
    }
    return '';
};
```

I noticed that the `value` being piped in must be a string. When I casted `value` to a string using `+''`, the error went away.

Comment: Thanks. I just remembered that after banging my head some days I just discovered that was the problem (I forgot to post an answer) :)